# Blank screen with local copy of site using MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I'm trying to set up a local copy of a currently live wordpress-based site using MAMP.

As far as I know I carried out all the necessary steps correctly (I have a working local copy of another wordpress site) but when I try to access the site all I see is a completely blank page.
I read that it might be a php issue but I'm a bit stuck as to how I can go about investigating this.

I also tried turning on WP_DEBUG in the hope that I'll see some error messages but to no avail, although I am still on a steep learning curve with Wordpress & programming in general so I may have done something wrong.

I'm at a bit of a dead end, can anyone suggest how I could investigate this issue. If it's a problem with the site how can I test that? This is the site in question- www.goodskiguide.com

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Jo

Comment: I looked at the apache error log within MAMP & found this error- [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
Could this be what is causing this issue?

Comment: The message `client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store` is just a security thing, nothing to worry about. It might have something to do with the base url of wordpress, did you change it? Furthermore your .htaccess might prevent things and are there any other messages in the log?